# Passing A Single Objects Into An MVC Controller Method Using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to post a single object data to an MVC Controler using JQuery, Below are my codes.

```
 //declare of type Object of GroupData
    var GroupData = {};
    //pass each data into the object 
    GroupData.groupName = $('#groupName').val(); 
    GroupData.narration = $('#narration').val();
    GroupData.investmentCode = $('#investmentCode').val();
    GroupData.isNew = isNewItem;
    //send to server
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/SaveContributionInvestGroup",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", 
            data: JSON.stringify({ GroupData: JSON.stringify(GroupData) }),

            success: function (res) {
                alertSuccess("Success", res.Message);

                //hide modal
                $('#product-options').modal('hide');

                hide_waiting();
            },
            error: function (res) {
                alertError("Error", res.Message);
            }
        });
```

Below is my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveContributionInvestGroup(ContributionInvestmentGroup GroupData)
    {
        ClsResponse response = new ClsResponse();
        ClsContributionInvestmentGroup clsClsContributionInvestmentGroup = new ClsContributionInvestmentGroup();

        var userID = (int)Session["userID"];
        var sessionID = (Session["sessionID"]).ToString();

        if (contributionGroupData != null)
        {
            //get the data from the cient that was passed
            ContributionInvestmentGroup objData = new ContributionInvestmentGroup()
            {
                contributionInvestmentGroupID = 0,
                groupName = GroupData.groupName,
                narration = GroupData.narration,
                investmentCode = GroupData.investmentCode,
                isNew = GroupData.isNew
            };

            response = clsClsContributionInvestmentGroup.initiateNewContributionInvestmentGroup(sessionID, objData);
        }
        else
        {
            response.IsException = true;
            response.IsSucess = false;
            response.Message = "A system exception occurred kindly contact your Administrator.";
        }


        return Json(new
        {
            response.IsSucess,
            response.Message
        });
    }
```

The issue is, the data is not been posted to the controller, the controller receives a null object.
Kindly assist, would really appreciate your effort, thanks.

Comment: You're sending `GroupData` yet the argument is `contributionGroupData`. You also may not need that outer structure depending on what your C# class looks like.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have set it to contributionGroupData, and it still doesn't work...

Comment: Its just `data: GroupData,` and remove the `contentType` option

Comment: And if you have generated you view correctly, then all you need to `var GroupData = $(yourForm).serialize();`

Comment: And if you did use `contentType: 'application/json` (which is unnecessary), then it would be `data: JSON.stringify({ GroupData: GroupData }),` or `data: JSON.stringify(GroupData);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like this:

```
//send to server
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
                url: "/Admin/SaveContributionInvestGroup",
                dataType: "json",
                data:  GroupData,
            success: function (res) {
                alertSuccess("Success", res.Message);

                //hide modal
                $('#product-options').modal('hide');

                hide_waiting();
            },
            error: function (res) {
                alertError("Error", res.Message);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Side note - `content: "application/json;",` is invalid - its `contentType` - but its fortunate that you have that typo because it would not work if you used `contentType`

Comment: @StephenMuecke No. I test ,doesnt work with `contentType` .

Comment: Yes I know - that is exactly what I stated - but you have `content: "application/json;",` in your code (which fortunately is invalid and ignored - there is no ajax option named `content`)

Answer (score -1):

in your controller your dont have `custom binding` to bind JSON to your model thats why you get null in you parameter.
instead just post it as query, try simply changes your ajax option like so:

```
{
        ...
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", //default: 
        ..., 
        data: $.param(GroupData),

        ...
}
```

and perhaps property names are case sensitive so you will need to change your javascript model's name

Comment: The `$.param` is not necessary (and the `DefaultModelBinder` is not case sensitive)